# How do I make the actual plot look like the correct plot?

Tags: matlab, plot, indexing, fft, convolution

The prompt is to develop a program to evaluate convolutions. This is to be done without using MATLAB's built in **conv** function. Therefore utilizing the Fourier transform, multiplying the two functions together and then inverse Fourier transforming the product. The transform is done by using direct integration. The **trapz** function is recommended form of integration to accomplish this goal.

I would appreciate **ANY** feedback on how to improve my code, please thoroughly explain what the improvements and link an reference as to how they work.

Given the code:

```
t = -5:.1:5;
w = pi;
X = zeros(101,1);
H = zeros(101,1);
Y = zeros(101,1);
y = zeros(101,1);
if t >= 0
x = 0;
h = 0;
else
x = exp((-3.*t)+(-1i*w.*t));
h = exp((-2*t)+(-1i*w.*t));
end
for k=2:101
X(k)=trapz(t(1:k),x(1:k));
H(k)=trapz(t(1:k),h(1:k));
Y = (X.*H)*exp(1i*w.*t);
y(k) = (1/(2*pi))*trapz(t(1:k),Y(1:k)); 
end
disp (length(x))
disp (length(X))
disp (length(Y))
disp (length(y))
    disp (y)
     figure(1);
     subplot(1,2,1),plot(t,real(y));grid on;
```

As I do not have enough reputation to directly post images, the actual output and desired output are as follows:

[The actual plot is this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZgeJJ.jpg)

[The desired plot is this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EPK7m.jpg)

My primary question is this: why is my plot not working?

Secondarily: What is unneeded in this code? What could make this code more efficient?

Comment: I have commented out the pre-allocation for zero vectors and that didn't seem to have an affect on the output, so I'm not sure if it is then useless to have it in there or not.

PS: If you downvote please explain why so I can improve the quality of future questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I won't do your entire homework, but I'll give you a few clues:

Skip the `if t < 0` part, it doesn't work. For your exam, try to understand why. If you can't figure it out, come with your best guess and you might get an explanation =)

Try the following instead (no loops or `if`s needed:

```
x = exp((-3.*t)+(-1i*pi.*t)).*(t>0);
```

And the same for `h`. Try to understand what `.*(t<0)` does in this context.

This one: `Y = (X.*H)*exp(1i*w.*t);` should be outside the loop. *Why?* Make a guess and you might get guidance if you're wrong.

Also `Y` is a 101x101 matrix. I guess you want it to be 101x1? You probably need to transform one of the vectors in the expression used to create `Y`. Before you do, you should figure out the difference between `'` and `.'` (an important difference in this case).

You are using `subplot`, but only plotting one graph. If you want to graphs in the same plot, use `hold on`. If you want to plots beside each other, remember to plot the second one too.

*And why use `w = pi;`, when you can just as well use `pi` in the equations?*

Comment: Best guess: I think the `if t < 0` doesn't work because it won't check the different values as a loop would.

`.*(t<0)` would appear to do what I want because it multiplies the matrix only by t when t is greater than zero making it like the desired step function multiplier. Why did you put `.*(t<0)` the second time? (typo?)

As for `Y = (X.*H)*exp(1i*w.*t);` I'm thinking that should go outside because it is an intermediate arithmetic process that will change as it is called upon by the next part of the code.

Am I close?

Comment: *The variable `w` was arbitrarily chosen to be pi, its a variable for easy manipulation of the output data, so I don't have to go through and replace it individually.*

I am using subplot in the case that I add another graph though I am currently looking up how to use `hold on`.

Comment: Here is an issue I am having, another person told me to try an make `x` and `h` like this:
> t= 0:.1:5;
> x1 = exp((-3.*t);
> x2 = zeros(1,50);
> x  = [x2 x1];

Which accomplishes the goal, but as far as coding goes this just takes so much time.

The `.*(t>0)` seems much more efficient but the syntax isn't working with the rest of the code. Would you be so kind as to explain what `.*(t>0)` is doing or send a link to an article that does?

Comment: Also after checking the code for `.*(t<0)` the values of x are **1** until the halfway point instead of **0** to the halfway point... is there a way I'm supposed to use it that would change it?

Comment: I don't have wifi in my apt yet (just moved), so I have to answer from my phone which is a pain. It should be t> 0 and not t<0, since the first one will be 0 for all ts less than 0. The .* performs a element-wise multiplication of zeros or one (depending on t). As for Y, you are not using it inside the loop and you are overwriting it every iteration. Only the last one is used, thus it could go outside.